# eclipse can not import some class automatically

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I have a spring-boot(maven) project and I have added the spring-security dependency into the pom.xml. When I am coding it cannot import some class about security automatically as the picture shows. I have to import the class by typing the full path, but I can not know all the class's full path. As the second picture shows I have to type the Highlight's code when I want to use some class. I cannot use ctrl + shift + O to import it. I have updated my dependency 
There is no problem in it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + O will manage the importing  of packages

Comment: Is the pom.xml file accepting the new dependency or is it giving you errors after the add?

Comment: does the version you added to the pom contain that class?

Comment: @L.Rex Show your added dependency from the pom.xml.

Comment: @user3437460 There is no error in my pom.xml I just want to import class by Ctrl + Shift + O instead by typing full class name.

Comment: @L.Rex Update your question with your added dependency.. I am pretty sure of what was the issue.

Comment: @user3437460 I have uploaded my pom.xml

Comment: Your artifactID should be... `spring-security-config`

Answer (score 0):

May be download of jar file is failed.
Check the Libraries of your project whether the required jar file is present in it or not.
If not then check pom.xml for any errors, if errors are not there then update your project.

```
Right_Click_On_Project->Maven->Update Project
```

Comment: The jar was downloaded and I can use it. I can find the class in the Libraries.

Comment: But the eclipse can not realize the class I have to import the class by typing the full path instead ctrl + shift + o

Comment: May be WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not present in jar, check

Answer (score 0):

If the download fails, I advise you to delete the failed jars and relative , too, because when you update your project, it will not download the jars that it thinks exists. I sometimes meet this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do.

1. In your screen shot itself if you click Fix project setup, it might pull your dependent jar.
2. Ctrl + Shift + O as Jayashree mentioned above can fix the problem.
3. Check your project Libraries -> Maven Dependencies -> and look you jar where WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class belongs to is present. If not then check your pom.xml
4. Lastly, right click your project and look for Maven -> Update Projects

One of the above steps should resolve your error.

Comment: I mean that the Libraries are all correct.  I have to import the class by typing the full path like import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; instead ctrl + shift + o when I want to import some class.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you should run maven properly after adding dependencies into your pom.xml file.
Right Click on pom.xml file then `Run As -> Maven Build...->(Goals)eclipse:eclipse.`

Refresh the project.

Check if new dependencies are added in to your project by: `Project Properites -> Java Build Path -> Libraries`

Comment: eclipse:eclipse has been deprecated for some time, although it does work. However, it should not be used with Eclipse Maven projects.